# Linux Prompt Does not Recognize Yes/No answer when removing a file

Tags: rm

I am using Centos 7. I tried to delete a file in the current directory as shown below:

```
[root@myserver ~]# rm foo
rm: remove regular file ‘foo’? yes
```

The server does not recognize my 'yes' answer and will not delete the file until I use the -f option.

`type rm` results in:

```
rm is aliased to `rm -i'
```

The output of `echo yes | xxd` is:

```
0000000: 7965 730a yes.
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What error do you get after you enter "yes"?

Comment: no error. It just assumes that I answered with "no".

Comment: Does this happen only for the `rm` command, or are there other examples? (Please update your post, if so)

Comment: it also happens when I try to install a package. I had to use -y with the yum install command.

Comment: I just noticed that "yes" is an executable file in the /bin directory. Could that be the problem?

Comment: a program prompting you for input *should not* be confusing that input with the  command in /bin, but I admit to being out of ideas.

Comment: How about just inputting `y` for yes? The only time I ever have to actually type out yes is when I’m accepting new ssh host keys.

Comment: Entering y for yes does not solve the problem